# Jenkins Perforce Plugin Exception

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I set up a Jenkins job to poll Perforce for changes in the depot every 15 minutes, however I am seeing the following error in the polling log:

```
Caught Exception communicating with perforce.P4 Where Parsing Error: //... and //some_depot/... filespecs are not allowed.

FATAL: Unable to communicate with perforce.  Check log file for: P4 Where Parsing Error: //... and //some_depot/... filespecs are not allowed.

java.io.IOException: Unable to communicate with perforce.  Check log file for: P4 Where Parsing Error: //... and //some_depot/... filespecs are not allowed.

    at hudson.plugins.perforce.PerforceSCM.compareRemoteRevisionWith(PerforceSCM.java:1296)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.poll(SCM.java:397)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject._poll(AbstractProject.java:1435)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.poll(AbstractProject.java:1338)
    at jenkins.triggers.SCMTriggerItem$SCMTriggerItems$Bridge.poll(SCMTriggerItem.java:119)
    at hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner.runPolling(SCMTrigger.java:515)
    at hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner.run(SCMTrigger.java:544)
    at hudson.util.SequentialExecutionQueue$QueueEntry.run(SequentialExecutionQueue.java:118)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Done. Took 5.4 sec
No changes
```

Has anyone seen this before? Polling seemed to work perfectly a few hours ago, but now this error is appearing with each poll.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your Perforce administrator just installed a new trigger, one which
generates the error message

```
//... and //some_depot/... filespecs are not allowed.
```

if it sees a client workspace spec with an unacceptable view map.

If that's indeed your problem, then you either have to specify a narrower (more precise) view map for the client workspace that your Jenkins build is using, or get your administrator to give you an exception in the trigger.